# Grails Elasticsearch plugin issues

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-orm, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new to Elasticsearch and am using the revived grails plugin "elasticsearch:0.0.4.6".

I wanted to implement a search for a User by their firstName, surname or username, which returns the full domain instance. 
I have a 2 domain classes:

User:

```
class User {

String firstName
String surname

static hasOne = [profile:Profile]
static hasMany = [friends:User]

static mappedBy  = [ friends: 'friends' ]

static searchable = {
    profile component:true
    only = ['firstName', 'surname', 'profile']
}
...
```

Profile:

```
class Profile {

String username
String status
byte[] photo

static belongsTo = [user:User]

static searchable = true
...
}
```

I made the classes "searchable = true" and then created the following search:

```
def res = User.search("${params.friendSearch}").searchResults
```

This found the correct instances, but now when a user adds a photo to their profile, it suceeds but I recieve a never ending loop of the following error:

**ERROR index.IndexRequestQueue  - Failed bulk item: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [photo]]; nested: NumberFor
matException[For input string:** the photos base64inputstring

I dont really get what is happening, but i figure it must be something to do with elasticsearch being unable to index the photo data. Can somebody provide an explanation?

I then experimented with searchables custom mapping options -

- profile index:'no'
- all=false
- excludeFromAll = true

etc

Nothing worked. Eventually I added

- only = ['username']

and it stopped the error from occuring and allowed me to find users based on the criteria i mentioned above. However, because of the "only" limit, it means that the User instances returned by the seach have a photo property equal to null, but i need this value!

What am i doing wrong? Can anyone advise me on the best course of action to take or any misunderstandings i have about Elasticsearch? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to exclude the byte property photo from the searchable fields like so:

```
class Profile {

String username
String status
byte[] photo

static belongsTo = [user:User]

static searchable = {
  except = ['photo']
}
```

This will exclude the property photo from being indexed and  search. Hence the output of converting the byte format to string format will not fail.

Also maybe you might need a custom convertor to change the byte(string) to something more usable in the results?